# CPU spikes cause audio stuttering in Audacious when browsing? (Lubuntu)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, browser, cpu

My default audio player is Audacious, browser Google Chrome. I tried Firefox, and while I love it, the CPU load spikes when doing something as simple and small and switching a tab, which causes the audio playing to stutter (as sound is onboard and handled thru the CPU). Chrome doesn't do this as much, but there is the occasional stuttering when browsing, which is ridiculous, as not even Windows Vista does this. So I thought maybe it's something to do with how Lubuntu handles sound, I checked and only ALSA was installed. I tried installing PulseAudio, but, while the music "plays", nothing comes through the speakers. Immediately after switching back to ALSA the music pours out of them.
So I was wondering if you had any idea what was going on here. I asked on Ubuntu Forums but apparently my problem is too complex, as it's been over a week since the last reply.

Specs are:

- AMD Athlon 64 3200+ @ 2GHz
- 2GB Corsair 667MHz DDR2 RAM
- ATi HD Radeon 3650 (AGP) 512MB
- 500W Cooler Master PSU
- 80GB SATA II HDD (Vista is installed on 500GB drive)
- Biostar K8M800 Motherboard

Answer (score 1):

Here are two things that you could try:

- If you have visualization plugins running, turn them off (this was enough for me to fix stutter)
- Adjust the buffer size (in `Preferences > Audio > Buffer size`), for example [this old redhat bug discussion](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=429389) suggests values around 500, while I think I had better luck with higher values.